# Find a class in vector of pointers to different classes

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading

So i have this:

```
class Grup : public Shape
{
private:
    std::vector<Shape *> continut;
public:
    static const std::string identifier;
    Grup(){};
    ~Grup(){
    continut.clear();
    };
    void add(Shape *);
    void remove(Shape *);
    void output(std::ostream &) const;
    void readFrom(std::istream &);
    void moveBy(int, int);
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, const Grup &);
}
```

and i want to implement the remove function.
i tried this:

```
void Grup::remove(Shape *s)
{
vector<Shape*>::iterator it;
it = continut.begin();
while(it!=continut.end())
{
    if((*it) == s)
    {
    it = continut.erase(it);
    }
    else it++;

}
}
```

but the == doesn't return me a true value. i also tried to overload the operator == on each shape but same result. what can i do?

Comment: Just two advices, use [`std::remove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) instead of a `while` (why type an algorithm wich is already typed on the stl?) and don't clear the vector in the destructor, it will be cleared anyways.

Comment: post your code of overloading operator== that didnt work

Comment: @makc i tried something like this: `bool Triunghi::operator==(const     Triunghi& T)
{
    if(this->identifier==T.identifier&&this-     >p1.getX()==T.p1.getX()&&this->p1.getY()==T.p1.getY()&&this->p2.getX()==T.p2.getX()&&this->p2.getY()==T.p2.getY()&&this->p3.getX()==T.p3.getX()&&this->p3.getY()==T.p3.getY())
  return 1;
 return 0;
}`

Comment: @user2116010 what does the identifier represents? Did you try debugging this code and check which parameter wasn't equal?

Comment: @makc yes i tried and it didn't even enter this overload function

Comment: @user2116010 make sure you didn't run optimized code, this is your real problem solve the debug problem and you'll be able to figure out the overloading problem

Answer (score 1):

This is comparing the memory addresses of two `Shape` objects:

```
if((*it) == s) // '*it' is of type `Shape*`
```

it is not comparing two `Shape` objects. A further dereference is required to use `operator==` defined for `Shape`. However, see [What's the right way to overload operator== for a class hierarchy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691007/whats-the-right-way-to-overload-operator-for-a-class-hierarchy) for a discussion on how to handle `operator==` for a class hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

you are comparing the shape pointers addresses and they are different.

you should overload **operator ==**

here are some examples:

[C++ Operator Overloading Guidelines](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html)

[Operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)