# Proper way of overloading binary relational operators in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, binary-operators, relational-operators

What is the proper/canonical way of overloading binary relational operators in C++?

Is it better to use **member functions**, or **`friend` free functions**?

E.g.:

```
class X {
 public:
  ...

  // Use member function overloads
  bool operator==(const X& rhs) const { 
    return m_text == rhs.m_text; 
  }

 private:
  std::string m_text;
};
```

or:

```
class X {
 public:
  ...

  // Use friend free function overloads
  friend bool operator==(const X& lhs, const X& rhs) { 
    return lhs.m_text == rhs.m_text; 
  }

 private:
  std::string m_text;
};
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691007/whats-the-right-way-to-overload-operator-for-a-class-hierarchy?rq=1) might help maybe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one thing you should be aware of are implicit conversions.

If your class supports implicit conversions from other types, it may be useful to make *operator==* a friend to support implicit conversions on its first arguments.

In other cases I suppose that it is more the matter of style.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but implicit conversions take place even with member operators.

Comment: @BrunoFerreira basically, parameters are eligible for implicit conversions only if they are listed in the parameters list, but when *operator==* is a member function the first parameter is *this* and it is not eligible for implicit conversion.

Comment: Sure. [I made a small test case](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5eefd0778684b48e) and yes, if i remove the implicit conversion to int it fails.

Comment: Giving it a better thought, member functions are `__thiscall`, meaning that it has an implicit `this` as first parameter. In my test case, it should be something like `bool operator==(A* this, int x)`. By C++ standard, the first argument is the left side and the second, the right side.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't make much difference, *except* that

- an instance of `X` needs to be on the left-hand-side of the equality operator for the member version to work. If you ever want to write

  ```
  X x("hello");
  string s("hello");
  assert(s == x);
  ```

  you need a non-member.
- if you're implementing all the binary relational operators, that's a potentially large increase in your class's surface area.

  I'd generally prefer this kind of auxiliary interface to be kept apart from the main class logic where possible (unless, of course, your class's primary concern is comparison).

  Using non-friend free operators and a minimal public interface is perhaps even better.