# Why is using the assignment operator on a dereferenced pointer to interface not a compiler error?

Tags: c++, abstract-class

Why is using the assignment operator on a dereferenced pointer to a purely abstract interface not a compiler error? When could this ever be useful? It seems like it can only lead to subtle bugs as I've outlined below.

In order to have a globally accessible object, which implements an interface, with a default value, that I can later override, do I have to use a handle (pointer to a pointer -- or -- pointer to a std::unique_ptr), or is there another approach?

```
#include <iostream>

class Interface {
 public:
  virtual int Value() = 0;
};

class Implementation : public Interface {
 public:
  Implementation(int value) : value(value) {}
  int Value() override {
    return value;
  }
  int value;
};

// Set default value
Interface* object = new Implementation(1);
Implementation* object2 = new Implementation(2);

int main() {
    // Why is this line not a compiler error?
    *object = Implementation(3); // Try to override default value
    *object2 = Implementation(4); // Override default value
    // This outputs "14", not "34", why?
    std::cout << object->Value() << object2->Value();
    return 0;
}
```

To get around these issues, as well as allow setting the overriding the default value in unit tests, I have gone with the following approach.

```
// Set default value
static std::unique_ptr<Interface> object(new Implementation(1));
void SetObject(std::unique_ptr<Interface> obj) {
    object.reset(obj.release());
}

int main() {
    SetObject(std::make_unique<Implementation>(2)); // Override default value
    std::cout << object->Value();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ objects by default get an `operator=` method generated by the compiler. This operator simply applies `operator=` to each of the member variables, and it is *not* virtual. That means it will work with the members of the *static* type of the declared pointer. Since `Interface` doesn't have any members, no members will be copied. `Implementation` has a member, so that member will be copied.

Comment: I see. So the real problem was my claim that "Interface" was a "pure abstract interface". It actually isn't. In order for that to be the case, I would need to add a few more things like deleting the default functions in order for there to be the compiler error I would expect. "Interface& operator=(const Interface&) = delete;"

Comment: Is there a way to make the assignment operator on the interface virtual, and allow it to be overridden in such a way that I can get the final output of my main function to be "34"?

Comment: @AffluentOwl Add another virtual function to the class, something like `CopyAssign()` that subclasses can implement, then implement `operator=` to simply call that function

Comment: Mark, given your response, it isn't clear to me why this line works "Interface* object = new Implementation(1);". Is it not actually using the assignment operator? Because object should not gain the value of "1" if the assignment operator would only copy the fields from the Interface class.

Comment: @AffluentOwl assignment of a pointer (`object =`) is *not* the same as assignment of an object (`*object =`).

Comment: @AffluentOwl see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691007/whats-the-right-way-to-overload-operator-for-a-class-hierarchy for options to implement `operator=` on a class hierarchy.

Comment: I think the confusion came from not understanding that the Implementation class can have more than one assignment operator based upon the type on the RHS. `Implementation& operator=(const Interface& other) override` and `virtual Implementation& operator=(const Implementation& other)`