# What is the recommended way to enforce that a class hierarchy is hashable?

Tags: c++, oop

I am trying to design a class hierarchy in which all derived classes must be hashable (so they need to provide a specialization for `std::hash<T>` and they need to be equally comparable). I want to avoid having to do this for each new derived class.

As far as I know, the `std::hash<T>` specialization needs to be defined outside the class. The `operator==` overload is also recommended to not be a member of the class. So, in other words, these operations would not be part of the "interface" of the base class.

To overcome this, I've defined virtual member functions that all derived classes should implement, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691007/whats-the-right-way-to-overload-operator-for-a-class-hierarchy). Then, to not have to specialize `std::hash<T>` for each subclass, I have used the new concept `std::derived_from<T>`.

Is this a recommended approach or does it create problems that I have not thought about? Should I simply document that derived classes should overload `operator==` and specialize `std::hash<T>`?

Here is an example implementation of the base class:

```cpp
#include <functional>

class Hashable {
    friend bool operator==(const Hashable &lhs, const Hashable &rhs);

    friend std::hash<Hashable>;

    [[nodiscard]] virtual bool is_equal(const Hashable &rhs) const = 0;

    [[nodiscard]] virtual std::size_t hash() const = 0;
};

bool operator==(const Hashable &lhs, const Hashable &rhs) {
    return typeid(lhs) == typeid(rhs) && lhs.is_equal(rhs);
}

template<>
struct std::hash<Hashable> {
    std::size_t operator()(const Hashable &s) const noexcept { return s.hash(); }
};

template<std::derived_from<Hashable> T>
struct std::hash<T> {
    std::size_t operator()(const T &s) const noexcept { return std::hash<Hashable>{}(s); }
};
```

And an example implementation of a concrete derived class:

```cpp
class Foo : public Hashable {
public:
    explicit Foo(int value) : bar{value} {}

private:
    int bar;

    [[nodiscard]] bool is_equal(const Hashable &rhs) const override {
        if (const auto *p = dynamic_cast<const Foo *>(&rhs)) return bar == p->bar;
        return false;
    }

    [[nodiscard]] std::size_t hash() const override { return std::hash<int>{}(bar); }
};
```

I have tried to compile the provided example and it works as expected. I do not see any major downsides when compared to specializing `std::hash<T>` for each derived class individually.

Comment: Looks OK to me, although the virtual functions will add a bit of overhead (CRTP might be an option there).  And documenting things is never a bad idea.

Comment: Note that classes derived from `Foo` are not abstract, even if they don’t override those virtual functions. As is often the case, good documentation is the best solution.

Comment: Yes, you should simply document the requirements. Requiring `is_equal` and `hash` member functions instead of the actual requirements just adds noise.